# Slow down the code?

Tags: java, docker

When i start the docker it generates Logs (basically text). My problem is that it **verifies so fast** that it can't catch the logs and frames.size is 0.
***But If I debug the code. It returns size > 0.*** So I'm guessing it's too fast and I need to slow down the code.

How can I run the function for a certain amount of time? Or execute x amount of ms after start?

```
 dockerClient.startContainerCmd(environmentName).exec();
 // I need to slow down here I think.
 List<Frame> frames = DockerLogs.getDockerLogs(dockerClient,container.getId());
 //remove after
  dockerClient.removeContainerCmd(environmentName).exec();




public static List<Frame> getDockerLogs(DockerClient dockerClient,String containerID) throws InterruptedException {

    List<Frame> frames = new ArrayList<>();

    dockerClient.logContainerCmd(containerID)
            .withStdOut(true)
            .withTailAll()
            .exec(new LogContainerResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Frame item) {
                    frames.add(item);
                    super.onNext(item);
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    super.onComplete();
                }
            }).awaitCompletion();

    return frames;
}
```

Comment: Try Thread.sleep(x)

Comment: I edited my code. I want to start, read logs and remove it.

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000) didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

`DockerLogs.getDockerLogs()` seems to be asynch(), so no matter how delay you introduce, you won't get expected results nor delay itself is a good idea. Whatever "wait time" you decide to use, there will be a case in which it is inadeguate.

Instead, try following docker's asynch pattern and provide a second callback to do the cleanup (removeContainerCmd). Basically you can't know WHEN it will finish, as the call to log returns immediately